# Black Map in iOS Google Maps

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

In iOS, I'm trying to show a Google map with a customized style: all black except for white roads.  The Google Maps Javascript library offers a "styled maps" option, but the iOS library does not.  At first, I was using the Javascript library within a UIWebView, except it turned out that iOS webkit suffers from glitches with touch events, so I've got to use the native iOS library instead. Is there a workaround (maybe involving a graphics hack) that could let me achieve nearly the effect that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be a Google Map, for example could you use MapBox? They support custom styles, and have an iOS SDK. They're not free through (depending how much traffic you have - there's a free tier for low amounts of traffic).

There's an example here:

http://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-streets-ios-screencast/

There is a feature request to add styles to the Google Maps iOS SDK here:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4968